# CSS horizontal scroll snap to TOP of a slide

Tags: javascript, html, css, horizontal-scrolling

(Edit: the JS in the original post was included by a mistake - it's now deleted)

I have a horizontal scroll working perfectly fine.

The problem is that my slides are vertical scrollable (and this is all good bc there's a lot of content) which means when I scroll down to the bottom of slide 1 and then scrolls horizontally to slide 2 the viewport does snap to the left of slide 2 but the viewport stays at the bottom of the slide. I want the viewport to snap to the TOP of slide 2 as well.

I haven't been able to find a solution to this, and there only seem to be `start`, `end` and `center` as working values for `scroll-snap-align` which doesn't solve my problem.

Does anyone know a way around this?

See the codesnippet below.

```css
#slidesContainer {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  overflow: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

#slides {
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  font-size: 100px;
  position: static;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  scroll-snap-stop: always;
}
```

```html
<div id="slidesContainer">
  <div id="slides" style="background-color:blue;">Slide 1<br><br> Scroll down until there is no more text, then scroll right text text text text text text text text text text text text text </div>
  <div id="slides" style="background-color:green;">Slide 2<br><br>This text is not visible unless you scroll back up - this is the problem.</div>
  <div id="slides" style="background-color:yellow;">Slide 3<br><br></div>
</div>
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: It's so hard to understand what you're trying to say without any visuals. Do you have a visual prototype/wireframe/gif/ screenshot of what you want to accomplish and what you have as a result ? Can you also put your HTML/CSS/JS code in a Runnable `Snippet` ? You want your horizontal scroll to be vertically scrollable ?

Comment: @maiakd I've recreated a simple code snippet. If you scroll down on slide 1 until there's no more text and then scroll horizontally you can't see the title "Slide 2" unless you scroll to the top. I'm looking for a way to have this happen automatically.

Comment: It's invalid to reuse IDs. An ID that isn't unique doesn't ID anything. Use classes instead, which is better practice anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly, this should work just fine. Essentially I added a custom scroll bar via CSS under the note `/* manual scrollbar */`. You can style it as you desire, but I just made it basic. Then you can get the horizontal scrollbar to the top of your elements using `transform: rotateX(180deg);` The notes I added with the additions in your CSS should help.

```css
#slidesContainer {
  height: 100vh;
  width: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  overflow: scroll;
  /* important for manual scrollbar to show */
}

#slides {
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 100px;
  position: static;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}


/* manual scrollbar */

#slidesContainer::-webkit-scrollbar {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 0px;
}

#slidesContainer::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}


/* Puts scrollbar at top */

div#slidesContainer {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

div#slidesContainer * {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}


/* for good measures */

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="slidesContainer">
  <div id="slides" style="background-color:blue;">Slide 1<br><br> text text text text text text text text text text text text text </div>
  <div id="slides" style="background-color:green;">Slide 2<br><br></div>
  <div id="slides" style="background-color:yellow;">Slide 3<br><br></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Kameron. I don't need a horizontal scroll bar. Sorry if I'm not making the question clear. I've updated the code snippet so it's hopefully more clear.

The problem is regarding the horizontal scroll snap. When I'm scrolled down on slide 1 (blue) and then scroll right to slide 2 (green) then it maintains the vertical scrolled position. When I scroll right I want it to `scroll-snap-align: start;`and I also want it to snap to the top of slide so the user won't miss the text at the very top of a slide. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: @AndyS Before I answer again I want to make sure we are relatively on the same page. Can you share a screenshot or markup image of what the desired goal is? I am still a bit confused.

Comment: Thanks for the patience!
I have made a horizontal scroll (please see the code snippet) which has the CSS code `scroll-snap-align:start;` to snap the viewport to left side of the slide when scrolling horizontally. As illustrated on slide 1 the scenario is that there is a lot of text on one slide so the user is able to scroll vertically. Say the user scrolls to the bottom of slide 1 and then scrolls horizontally, the viewport stays at the bottom. What I basically want is for the viewport to always snap to the top of a slide - not just to the left of a slide. Lmk if this is sufficient.

Comment: Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: @AndyS working on one now.